# Predict Stock Buy or Hold in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, prediction

I am currently using Random Forest Regressor to predict stock prices and to decide whether to Buy or Hold the stock based on the predicted result. My code isn't resulting "BUY" or "HOLD" instead it results True or False.
How can I fix this issue?
[image]

Comment: remove the '?' in 'Buy_Hold?'

Answer (score 0):

The panda's data framework correctly with the whole syntax, I tried a similar snippet of code and it worked fine.
Maybe try using, **print(Result['Buy_Hold?'])**

Make sure to add the "?" in the column name as well.

PS. You can not create the perfect algorithm for the stock market it depends on the emotions of investors as well :)